# com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null

Tags: apache-axis

After implementing MultiThread concept I tested my application in below ways.

1. First I tried to  insert two records through SOAP UI It was inserted properly.
2. I tried to insert 100 records. It was inserted successfully.
3. I tried to insert 600 records. It was also inserted Successfully.
4. I tried to insert 1500 records  but I will get below Exception.

Please let me know why below exception are coming.

JDK1.5,axis2 1.4 are the configuration used for this application.

```
 org.apache.axis2.AxisFault
        at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:83)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.sendUsingOutputStream(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:337)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:214)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:448)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:43)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:100)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:176)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:275)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:133)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:620)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseNsStreamWriter.doWriteEndTag(BaseNsStreamWriter.java:671)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseNsStreamWriter.writeEndElement(BaseNsStreamWriter.java:282)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.MTOMXMLStreamWriter.writeEndElement(MTOMXMLStreamWriter.java:129)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeEndpart(OMSerializerUtil.java:61)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:926)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerializeAndConsume(OMElementImpl.java:947)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:918)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerializeAndConsume(OMElementImpl.java:947)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:918)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerializeAndConsume(OMElementImpl.java:947)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:918)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerializeAndConsume(OMElementImpl.java:947)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:918)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerializeAndConsume(OMElementImpl.java:947)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:918)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerializeAndConsume(OMElementImpl.java:947)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.serializeInternally(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:240)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.internalSerialize(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:228)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerializeAndConsume(OMElementImpl.java:947)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMNodeImpl.serializeAndConsume(OMNodeImpl.java:471)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:79)
        ... 22 more
    Caused by: ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:369)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:448)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:363)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:392)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:381)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:89)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:109)
        at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.write(UTF8Writer.java:139)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flushBuffer(BufferingXmlWriter.java:1103)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.fastWriteRaw(BufferingXmlWriter.java:1126)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.writeEndTag(BufferingXmlWriter.java:796)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseNsStreamWriter.doWriteEndTag(BaseNsStreamWriter.java:669)
        ... 42 more
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:761)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:448)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:363)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer$OutputStreamOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:785)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:126)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:598)
        at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:533)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:364)
        ... 54 more
    [ERROR]
```

Answer (score 2):

> Please let me know why below exception are coming.

The exception is thrown because the client closed the connection before the server got a chance to write the response.